# Fonts with slanted e

Tags: fonts, font-identification, typefaces

Someone know where we can find or style name of this typefaces with slanted e?

[image]

Comment: Since that is a logo, I would very much assume that "e" was slanted manually

Comment: yes, but some typefaces come with letters already slanted

Comment: there are some, but there's no specific category name if that's what you're asking

Comment: Walter Tracy's famous book on fonts *Letters of Credit* calls it a lazy way to make a font distinctive, incidentally. I certainly don't think it looks good in extended text.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree with @Cai that this is VERY likely a completely custom logo-type.

However [ITC Kabel](https://www.fonts.com/font/itc/itc-kabel) has a tilted e:

[image]

As does the free [New Republic](http://www.1001freefonts.com/sf_new_republic.font):

[image]

It's worth mentioning I think that the one-stop shop to duplicating that logo looks to be some kind of Helvetica bold, and a rotated e! In fact I just searched and this turned up [Lenovo Font](https://www.thinkscopes.com/download/lenovo-logo-font-2015/) - Might be worth a try?

You cannot fault Saatchi and Saatchi for the [work they put in](http://www.underconsideration.com/brandnew/archives/new_logo_and_identity_for_lenovo_by_saatchi_saatchi_new_york.php) rotating that e ;)

Comment: Thanks for the edit @Cai I'll include screen-grabs in future, very useful :)

Comment: No problem, yeh it's best to include some screenshots with font recommendations if you can

Comment: thank you @mayersdesign. that's right. well, i  any case seems very interesting if the Foundries categorize this kind of style on typeface

Answer (score 2):

Poiret One has a beautiful slanted "e". I found it in Google Fonts.

Comment: I love Poiret One, especially that tilted lowercase 'e'! I only wish it came in various stroke thicknesses. If it came in regular and medium-bold, in addition to 'light', I'd use it for everything.

Answer (score 1):

Kessel 205 is similar to Poiret One. The zero is less confusing. Beyond that, each has it's own charm. I still wish both came in heavier variants.

[image: sample fonts]

Answer (score 0):

Product Sans is the answer....

Comment: Hello user174533, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. While you might be correct, it's not very useful as it stands. For font identification questions, we usually expect the answer to include some visual evidence, like a screenshot of the font. In this case, of the slanted e especially.

Answer (score 0):

i like these fonts with the slanted "e"

Clemente, and Josefin-Sans

Comment: Hello Deleon Randal, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. While you might be correct, it's not very useful as it stands. For font identification questions, we usually expect the answer to include some visual evidence, like a screenshot of the font. In this case, of the slanted e especially.